# Vee-Validate 3 - Poperty or method "alpha_spaces" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-9, vee-validate, php-8.2

I am using vee-validate 3 with Vue 2 and custom components. I need to validate the firstname field, the rules `required_if`, `max` and `alpha_spaces` work fine but I'm getting an error 'Property or method "alpha_spaces" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render'. I already defined the `alpha_spaces` rule but still getting this error. Is there anything that I'm missing?

```
<template>
    <div class="tw-mt-10">
        <ValidationObserver tag="form" ref="validationobserver">
            <form>
                <div class="tw-flex-col tw-w-1/2 tw-ml-10">
                    <div class="tw-flex tw-space-x-5">
                        <label>Details not known</label>
                        <ValidationProvider name="Details not known" v-slot="{ errors }">
                            <checkbox
                                id="details_not_known"
                                ref="details_not_known"
                                type=""
                                v-model="form.details_not_known"
                                :error="form.getError('details_not_known') || errors[0]"
                                @updated="form.details_not_known = $event"
                            ></checkbox>
                        </ValidationProvider>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tw-flex tw-space-x-5 tw-mt-10">
                        <label>Firstname</label>
                        <ValidationProvider mode="passive" name="Firstname" :rules="{required_if:!form.details_not_known, max:35, alpha_spaces}" v-slot="{ errors }">
                            <text-field
                                ref="firstname"
                                v-model="form.firstname"
                                :error="form.getError('firstname') || errors[0]"
                                @updated="form.firstname = $event"
                            ></text-field>
                        </ValidationProvider>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tw-flex tw-mt-10">
                        <button type="button" @click="add()" class="tw-bg-blue-800 tw-text-white tw-rounded-sm tw-px-3 tw-py-1">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </ValidationObserver>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {Form} from 'form-backend-validation';
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';
import { ValidationObserver, extend } from 'vee-validate';
import { required, required_if, numeric, alpha_spaces, between, min, max } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';

extend('required', {
    ...required,
    message: '',
});

extend('required_if', {
    ...required_if,
    message: '',
});

extend('alpha_spaces', {
    ...alpha_spaces,
    message: 'Must only contain alphabetical characters',
});

extend('max', {
    validate(value, { length  }) {
        return value.length <= length;
    },
    params: ['length'],
    message: 'Must be {length} characters long'
});

export default {

    components: {ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver, extend},

    data() {
        return {
            form: new Form.create()
                .withOptions({resetOnSuccess: false})
                .withData({
                    details_not_known: false,
                    firstname: '',
                })
        }
    },

    methods: {
        add() {
            console.log(this.$refs.validationobserver);

            this.$refs.validationobserver.validate().then(valid => {
                if (valid) {
                    console.log("VALID!");
                } else {console.log("NOT VALID!");
                    //
                }
            });
        },
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding a `true` value to `alpha_spaces`. So it should look like this

```
<div class="tw-flex tw-space-x-5 tw-mt-10">
    <label>Firstname</label>
    <ValidationProvider mode="passive" name="Firstname" :rules="{required_if:!form.details_not_known, max:35, alpha_spaces: true}" v-slot="{ errors }">
         <text-field
              ref="firstname"
              v-model="form.firstname"
              :error="form.getError('firstname') || errors[0]"
               @updated="form.firstname = $event"
          ></text-field>
    </ValidationProvider>
</div>
```

https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/advanced/rules-object-expression.html#defining-rules